# Matrix - Select everything except specified indices

Tags: r, matrix

I know that you can directly select the indices of a matrix you want by doing:

```
mat <- matrix(1:6,ncol=3)
select <- matrix(c(1,2,1,2,3,3),ncol=2)
colnames(select) = c("row","col")

mat[select]
#[1] 3 6 5
```

Is there a way in R to select all the elements in a matrix except specific indices? This is allowed easily for vectors with `LETTERS[-1]`. Ideally, I could do something like `mat[-select]`, but when trying this, I get:

```
mat[-select]
#Error in mat[-select] : 
#  negative values are not allowed in a matrix subscript
```

What I've tried:

```
library(dplyr)
all_ind <- expand.grid(row=1:nrow(mat),col=1:ncol(mat))
keep<-anti_join(all_ind,as.data.frame(select))

mat[as.matrix(keep)]
#[1] 4 2 1
```

This works, but it requires some coercion and joining which isn't ideal. Maybe it's just me, but I couldn't seem to find any easy approaches to this.

Comment: The clumsy way: `mat[ - (select[,"row"] + (select[,"col"]-1)*nrow(mat)) ]`

Comment: Also, instead of expand.grid, you could use reshape2::melt(mat) directly in the anti-join. (I don't think tidyr has an analogue for this.)

Comment: @Frank thanks for both suggestions! The way you posted is definitely better than mine, feel free to post it as an answer and i'll accept

Comment: what about `mat[select] <- NA; na.omit(c(mat))` if there are no other NAs. or `mat[select] <- Inf; c(mat)[is.finite(c(mat))]` if you do have NAs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way, still pretty convoluted:

```
dplyr::anti_join(
  reshape2::melt(mat),
  as.data.frame(select),
  by=c(Var1 = "row", Var2 = "col")
)$value
# [1] 4 2 1
```

I'm using `reshape2:::melt.matrix` since I guess the 'verse has no analogue at this point.

---

Alternately, do the math to convert from matrix (or array) indices back to vector indices:

```
mat[ - (select[,"row"] + (select[,"col"]-1)*nrow(mat)) ]
# [1] 1 2 4
```

Comment: gather is the tidyverse equivalent of melt. But who wants to gather their data when you can melt it.

Comment: @IanWesley A question for the ages there. Fyi, I meant that tidyr doesn't seem to have anything to melt a matrix; as far as I could figure, gather is data.frames/data_frames/tbl_dfs/tiddlydoos only.

Answer (score 1):

```
setdiff(mat, mat[select])
#[1] 1 2 4
#Will most likely NOT WORK if there are duplicated values
```

Maybe a workaround can be to create another matrix (`ind`) with same dimension as `mat` but with indices as it's values. Then use the same approach as above

```
mat <- matrix(6:11,ncol=3) #NOTE this is different than in question
select <- matrix(c(1,2,1,2,3,3),ncol=2)
ind = matrix(1:length(mat), ncol = 3)
mat[setdiff(ind, ind[select])]
#[1] 6 7 9
```